# Date fields and formulas that change format

Tags: excel

I have a huge issue with trying to copy values onto my database

lets say i have 2 columns, A is integer and B is date

I'm trying to build column C with the expression

```
 = "(" &A2& ",'" & B2& "'),"
```

Expected output (1000, '2020-01-29'),

Obtained output (1000, '43859'), (?????)

Is there a function that allows me to do a formula but keep the date as it is?

Comment: Use the TEXT function.

Comment: @BigBen i tried text (D2) and it said too few arguments ?

Comment: Add the relevant argument -- the format code.  Examine HELP for the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to

`= "(" &A2& ",'" &TEXT(B2,"DD/MM/YY")& "'),"`

.

The `=TEXT()` function takes the value you want to format and the format as arguments.

`=TEXT(Value you want to format, "Format code you want to apply")`

[Click here for the TEXT function manual](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c)